# How do I datamine financial tables using Htmlunit?

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

Using java/htmlunit I want to data mine (web scrape) a bunch of hedge fund SEC 13F filings. I have no clue how to datamine the SEC's .txt files such as [This Table](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1047644/000104746912006072/a2209520z13f-hr.txt).
The table layout seems clean and structured, but how do I grab the `< Table >` with corresponding `< S >` and `< C >`? Moreover, how can I grab just the company names and `< C >` Value (in column 3) and `< C >` Shares Amt (in column 4).

Not sure if I'm on the right track, but I used Bufferedreader, not sure what to do next to grab the data within the `< Table >` ... Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1047644/000104746912006072/a2209520z13f-hr.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;


        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: HtmlUnit won't help you here, because the page doesn't contain HTML, but plain text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Suggestions? I'm planning on looping through about 200 hedge funds. How do i go about web scraping / datamining plain text in an address such as  http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1047644/000104746912006072/a2209520z13f-hr.txt  Also, what is the proper terminology for a a web address that ends in .txt?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of format this document has but HTMLUnit will, at most, allow you to download it from the web. You'll have to do the parsing on your own.

Now, the format doesn't seem to be XML, HTML nor any standard format (at least from the small amount I know)... So, I first thought about regular expressions but after a second thought I realised that you've got the length of the columns represented by the amount of dashes `(-)`.

You can use regular expressions to get everything between the `<table>` tags and then use any programming language to split the dash line into an array of strings and then cut the text of each line below by the amount of characters of each of those strings.

That'd be it :)

Comment: This will work for a .txt file? Also, a lot of these SEC filings are all over the place. Some use (-) marks, others use straight lines like http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1037389/0001037389-12-000061.txt Is there an efficient way to create a more robust code to handle these different .txt formats?

Comment: @ETD33 If the language is not standarized and documented you won't be able to find a parser out there. My guess is that even if that language is well documented nobody took the time to write some kind of parser. So, again, you'll have to write it from scratch. The good thing is that if you do, you can publish your parser and help other with the same problem :)

Comment: I really want to learn how to do this... But i dont know how to "use regular expressions to get everything between the < table > tags and then use any programming language to split the dash line into an array of strings and then cut the text of each line below by the amount of characters of each of those strings." Can you point me in the right direction?